# Copying data into new sheet depending upon selection of rows or columns based upon highlighted

Tags: vba, excel, copying

This question may be posted on other forums as well but i am unable to find out my answer.

I want a macro that could

- Copy my selected rows or columns or cells.
- makes new file.xlsx
- pastes that data in that sheet.

Comment: Did you try recording a macro and seeing how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to paste it into a certain place or just the start of the sheet? What would determine whether you copy the row or column?

This will copy the row of your currently selected cell and then paste it into the first row of a new workbook

```
Sub CopyRow()
  Selection.EntireRow.Copy
  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

### Edit

Add this code to ask if you want to save, you could then have a question to copy row or column or have a separate macro to copy the column.

```
Dim docname As String
If MsgBox("Would you like to save the doc?", vbYesNo, "Save?") = vbYes Then
 docname = InputBox("What would you like to call the doc?", "Title")
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=docname, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
End If
```

Comment: actually i want that whenever i select multiple rows or columns and then run a macro, that macro starts pasting those selected rows or columns in new workbook with option for saveas so that i can give it my specified name

Comment: Check my updated code, if you have a specific criteria for whether it copy's row or column that can be added at the top of the code. If you highlight more than 1 cell it will copy all corresponding rows

Comment: Fantastic. Thankyou so Much. i changed for the column myself.

Comment: one more thing if you could answer? now i have two macros one for rows and one for columns now could there be any button by which if pressed it launches a dialog box and ask which macro you want to perform and then launches the specified macro onclick? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you could create a user form with a dropdown to select row or column, or input box where you enter something i.e. row or column, r or c. Followed by an if statement. If input = c, then call  copyrow (bring the name of the macro to call.), this way does leave room for input error though. I'm on my mob at the mo, won't be at a laptop until Sunday, I can get the code written up for you then if you need. But of a pain writing on the mob!